# Show that two functions have the same minimizer

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

Define the following two functions:
\begin{align}
g(x)&=1_{\{  \langle v_1,x \rangle  \ge 0 \} }+1_{\{  \langle v_2,x \rangle \ge 0  \} },\\
f(x)&=1_{\{  \langle v_1,x \rangle  \ge 0 \} } \langle v_1,x \rangle +1_{\{  \langle v_2,x \rangle \ge 0  \} } \langle v_2,x \rangle,
\end{align}
where the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are given.  Here, as usual,  $1_{ \{\cdot \}}$, denotes the indicator function. We further restric $x$ to be $\|x\|=1$.

I would like to show that if $x^\star$ is a minimizer of $f(x)$, then it is also a minimizer of $g(x)$.

Intuitively a minimizer of $f$ forces the inner products to be either negative or very close to zero and this, in turn, should minimize $g$.  However, I am not very sure what arguments to use to show this.

**Edit:** Based on comments this appears to be true up to a set of measure zero for $(v_1,v_2)$.  However, not all details are clear to me yet.

Comment: just to make sure you understand the 'set of measure zero': take $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $v_1=v_2=(1,0)$, then $x=(0,1)$ minimizes $f$ but not $g$

Comment: @LinAlg I know what a set measure zero means.  I can't follow the proof belwo that shows that these sets of zeros differ by a set of measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of minimisers is almost the same, basically they can differ by a set of measure $0$ when $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not colinear with different sign.

Assume first that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not colinear with different sign. In essence, we assume that $v_1 \ne -c v_2$ for some $c > 0$. We observe that $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ have image in $[0,\infty)$ so that if there exists $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$, then the minimising set for $f$ is its zero set, and similarly for $g$. Set

$$\hat x = \left(\frac{v_1}{\|v_1\|} +  \frac{v_2}{\|v_2\|}\right)$$
and
$$x^\star = \frac{\hat x}{\|\hat x\|}$$

It is not too hard to see that $f(x^\star) = g(x^\star) = 0$ and that $\|x^\star\| = 1$, the latter condition holding because $v_1 \ne -c v_2$.  Therefore, since both $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative functions, the set which Now, it is clear that $g(x) = 0$ implies $f(x) = 0$. However, there are always vectors such that $f(x) = 0$ while $g(x) \ne 0$. To have $g(x) = 0$, we need two conditions: $\langle x,v_1 \rangle < 0$ and $\langle x,v_2\rangle < 0$, whereas to have $f(x) = 0$ we need $\langle x,v_1\rangle \le 0$ and $\langle x, v_2 \rangle \le 0$. We therefore have that
$$
\{x : f(x) = 0 \text{ and } g(x) \ne 0\} = (\operatorname{span}(v_1)^\perp \cap \{x : \langle x,v_2\rangle \le 0\}) \cup (\operatorname{span}(v_2)^\perp \cap \{x : \langle x,v_1\rangle \le 0\}).
$$
This is the union of two intersections of a half-space with a codimension 1 subspace, so it has codimension 1 in the unit sphere.

If $v_1 = -c v_2$ for some $c > 0$, the picture is completely different. Then,
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x \in \operatorname{span}(v_1)^\perp = \operatorname{span}(v_2)^\perp \\
> 0 & \text{otherwise },
\end{cases}
$$
whereas
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
2 & \text{if } x \in \operatorname{span}(v_1)^\perp = \operatorname{span}(v_2)^\perp \\
1 & \text{otherwise }.
\end{cases}
$$
This means that in this situation their minimising sets are completely disjoint.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to add a restriction on $x$. Sorry.

Comment: I adapted the answer to fit your restriction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some questions if you don't mind. When you sat set $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (...)$ is that meant as an example? Do you assume this $x$ through the rest of your answer?

Comment: I give an example of a point where $f(x) = g(x) = 0$. Since both functions are nonnegative, this tells us that the set minimising either function is the zero set of that function.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The claim that the set of a minimizer for both functions is their zero is general not just for this example, right?  Also, how do you show this? Sorry for all these questions, but I would really like to fully understand the solution to this problem.

Comment: If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are collinear, I don't think the minimum of $g$ can be $2$. I think the minimum is at most one.

Comment: So both $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative functions right? As in their image is in $[0,\infty)$. So if I find a point $y$ where, say, $f(y) = 0$. Then because the functions cannot be negative this $y$ is clearly a minimum. This is a feature of this specific example. Now, by definition all other $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$ are also minimums.

Comment: Indeed, if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are colinear, the minimum of $g$ is not $2$. That's the point: I  some $v$ minimising $f$ but not $g$.

Comment: ok. But how do you formally show that the sets of minimizes differ by at most a set of measure zero?

Comment: I'll modify the answer to have a more formal proof. The case when $v_1$ and $v_2$ are colinear but opposite is actually different.

Comment: I think I follow everything now. Thank you.  One thing though. I think your solution for $\hat{x}$ is missing a minus sign, right?

Comment: p.s I posted a related question here. 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3968157/does-a-minimizer-of-fx-sum-i-1n-1-langle-v-i-x-rangle-0-c