# Does a minimizer of $f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{ \langle v_i,x \rangle > 0 \} } \cdot \langle v_i,x \rangle $ makes most of the terms zero?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, vectors

Consider a collection of  2-d vectors $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$. Assume all of these are unit norm.   Let
\begin{align}
f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{ \langle v_i,x \rangle > 0 \} } \cdot \langle v_i,x \rangle 
\end{align}
where $1_{ \{ \cdot \} }$ is the indicator function.
We want to minimize  $f(x)$ over all unit norm vectors $x$.   The solution for $n=2$ is given in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962782/show-that-two-functions-have-the-same-minimizer).   Note there can be many minimizers.

**Questions:**   **Q1:** Is it true that that one of the minimizers of  $f$  makes the most inner product terms non-positive?
In other words,  define a set
\begin{align}
A= \arg \max_{x: \|x\|=1}  | \{v_i: \langle v_i,x \rangle  \le 0 \}| ,
\end{align}
where $|\cdot |$ is the cardinality operator. The set $A$ contains $x$ that make the most inner producs negative.  Then, one of the  minimizers of $f$ is member of a set $A$.

In essence, the question is asking if there exists a minimizer of $f$ that first makes as many as possible of the terms to be equal to zero.

For $n=2$, where we know the solution, this is true.  It might happen that there exists a choice of $v_i$'s such that this is not true (see in the answers).

**Q2:** Under what conditions on $v_i$'s is this true?

Comment: In the question you ask about a minimizer that 'makes the most inner products negative', but in the set $A$ you count nonpositive inner products. The distinction between negative and nonpositive is important because it is exactly the set of measure zero you mention later.

Comment: @LinAlg I suspect this is due to a "false friend".  In French, for instance, "négatif" means nonpositive, and "strictement négatif" means negative.

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks. I mean non-positve. I will correct this.

Comment: This is very confusing notation to me. Is $1_{ \{ \langle v_i,x \rangle > 0 \} } \cdot \langle v_i,x \rangle $ meant to be $\max\{0,  \langle v_i,x \rangle\}$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri. Sure. These are equal.

Comment: I guess then the indicator function should be $1_{\left\{ v \,:\, \langle v_i, v\rangle > 0\right\}}(x)\cdot\langle v_i, x \rangle$, is that so?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 7):

Let $n=5$, $\varepsilon$ be a sufficiently small positive number, $v_1=(0,1)$, $v_2=(0,-1)$, $v_3$ equals $v_1$ rotated by an angle $\varepsilon$ clockwise, $v_4$ equals $v_2$ rotated by an angle $\varepsilon$ counter-clockwise, and $v_5=(-1,0)$. Then $A=\{(-1,0)\}$, but $f(-1,0)=1$, whereas $f(1,0)=2\sin\varepsilon<1$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this counterexample. Do you think it possible to find a condition on vectors 's such that the most inner product terms need to be non-positive

Comment: @Lisa I do no see such non-trivial conditions now.